# AA Video Game Companies

Tags: jobs, gameaudio

Hey all,

So "AAA" companies advertise jobs on gamasutra.com, gameaudio101.com, etc etc.

What about "AA" companies? Where do they get their employees? How do they hire and is there a place where they advertise job openings like the previously mentioned pages?

Gamedevmap.com is the best site I have known to find ALL game companies, but its extremely time consuming to visit every single one of their sites in every state to see what jobs they have available. Is this literally the best way to go about it?

Thanks for your thoughts!
C3

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check http://www.gamedev.net forum.

Comment: Definitely has been on my browsing list for a good while! Thanks for the post bump!

Comment: Good luck! There´s a bunch of projects going on all the time, check the help wanted section in the forum!

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.gamecareerguide.com/jobs/.

Comment: Yep for sure - same with gameguzzler and gamasutra. Good sites! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to the industry and looking to get your feet wet in game audio with a lesser known company, what about looking on Craigslist? I've seen plenty of startups here in San Francisco looking for audio help on a budget.

Comment: Very good suggestion - im actually going to do this tonight! Thank you!